# Multiple Occurence in Array Do-Loop in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

I am trying to use Array Do loop to search through 8 variables. An observation is considered having multiple trauma if at least 2 variables meet the condition of falling between 800-959 excluding 905-909,910-924, and 930-939.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please include code that you have already attempted and more details about your question in your post.  As mentioned in the comments review the link for the guidelines on how to post questions correctly.

Since it is your first post and the problem is relatively simple, I'll give you my solution.

This can be done in a simple data step.  Since there are only 8 variables that we have to worry about, I just wrote an `if` statement for each variable to create a dummy variable with the conditions you specificed.  If the 8 dummy variables add up to 2 or more, then the final dummy variable `risk_ind = 1`.

Double check the conditions in the `if` statements.  I'm not sure if I understood that part of your question.  They are easy for you to adjust to your specific needs though.

See code below.

```
data trauma; input
row_num a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h; datalines;
1       800 100 600 550 820 950 930 55
2       700 960 999 300 230 100 805 120
3       200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200  
4       920 931 929 945 962 500 800 730  
run;

data multiple_trauma;
set trauma;

if (a >= 800 and a < 905) or (a > 924 and a < 930) or (a > 939 and a <959) then 
    a_dummy = 1;
    else a_dummy = 0;

if (b >= 800 and b < 905) or (b > 924 and b < 930) or (b > 939 and b <959) then 
    b_dummy = 1; 
    else b_dummy = 0;

if (c >= 800 and c < 905) or (c > 924 and c < 930) or (c > 939 and c <959) then 
    c_dummy = 1; 
    else c_dummy =  0;

if (d >= 800 and d < 905) or (d > 924 and d < 930) or (d > 939 and d <959) then 
    d_dummy = 1; 
    else d_dummy = 0;

if (e >= 800 and e < 905) or (e > 924 and e < 930) or (e > 939 and e <959) then 
    e_dummy = 1; 
    else e_dummy = 0;

if (f >= 800 and f < 905) or (f > 924 and f < 930) or (f > 939 and f <959) then 
    f_dummy = 1; 
    else f_dummy = 0;

if (g >= 800 and g < 905) or (g > 924 and g < 930) or (g > 939 and g <959) then 
    g_dummy = 1; 
    else g_dummy = 0;

if (h >= 800 and h < 905) or (h > 924 and h < 930) or (h > 939 and h <959) then 
    h_dummy = 1; 
    else h_dummy = 0;

total_risk_factors = a_dummy + b_dummy + c_dummy + d_dummy + e_dummy + f_dummy + g_dummy + h_dummy;

if total_risk_factors > 2 then risk_ind = 1;
   else risk_ind = 0;

run;

proc sql;
create table mulitple_trauma_ind as
select row_num, risk_ind 
from work.multiple_trauma;
quit;
```